# Swap first and last name fields in a contact record

Tags: iphone, contacts

When contacts/address book was imported from a previous phone most of the entries came in with the last name in the first name field, and first name in the last name field.

Is there a quick key method to swap those two fields without having to retype both of them or cut/paste one and type the other?

Comment: You can export it to excel, change columns an re-import your contacts. Or you can  Automator/applescript.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  And if I export them, I will effectively have a backup, too.  Now I will just have to learn how to do the export.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You could change the sort order and display order of the contacts in Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars under the Contacts section to give the *appearance* that the contacts are in that right order, though.